# Circular Threads in Java using Semaphores

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

I'd like to implement the `FizzBizz` game using 4 threads and Semaphores.
I managed to make threads to work in the desired order: `fizz() -> buzz() -> fizzBuzz() -> printNumber()`.
However, I can't manage to make the whole procedure circular.
Each method has it's own semaphore, and despite locking it's own semaphore right before releasing the next method semaphore, the methods just don't hang on the second acquire (which is the first one in the method, actually).

The desired behavior:
1. Lock all semaphores.
2. Start all 4 methods.
3. Release `fizz()` semaphore, making it go first.
4. `fizz()` finishes, releases `buzz()` lock and hangs until `printNumber()` releases it.
5. etc.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

class FizzBuzz {
    protected AtomicLong num = new AtomicLong(1);
    protected AtomicLong n = new AtomicLong(100);
    protected Semaphore sem1 = new Semaphore(1);
    protected Semaphore sem2 = new Semaphore(1);
    protected Semaphore sem3 = new Semaphore(1);
    protected Semaphore sem4 = new Semaphore(1);

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Started");
        try {
            sem1.acquire();
            sem2.acquire();
            sem3.acquire();
            sem4.acquire();
            this.fizz();
            this.buzz();
            this.fizzBuzz();
            this.printNumber();
            sem1.release();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void fizz() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (num.get() <= n.get()) {
                    try {
                        // System.out.println("Fizz waiting...");
                        sem1.acquire();
                        sem1.release();
                        if (num.get() > n.get()) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (num.get() % 3 == 0 && num.get() % 5 != 0) {
                            num.getAndIncrement();
                            System.out.println("Fizz");
                        }
                        sem1.acquire();
                        sem2.release();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void buzz() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (num.get() <= n.get()) {
                    try {
                        // System.out.println("Buzz waiting...");
                        sem2.acquire();
                        sem2.release();
                        if (num.get() > n.get()) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (num.get() % 5 == 0 && num.get() % 3 != 0) {
                            num.getAndIncrement();
                            System.out.println("Buzz");
                        }
                        sem2.acquire();
                        sem3.release();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void fizzBuzz() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (num.get() <= n.get()) {
                    try {
                        // System.out.println("FizzBuzz waiting...");
                        sem3.acquire();
                        sem3.release();
                        if (num.get() > n.get()) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (num.get() % 3 == 0 && num.get() % 5 == 0) {
                            num.getAndIncrement();
                            System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
                        }
                        sem3.acquire();
                        sem4.release();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void printNumber() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (num.get() <= n.get()) {
                    try {
                        // System.out.println("Print Number waiting...");
                        sem4.acquire();
                        sem4.release();
                        if (num.get() > n.get()) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (num.get() % 3 == 1 && num.get() % 5 == 1) {
                            num.getAndIncrement();
                            System.out.println(num);
                        }
                        sem4.acquire();
                        sem1.release();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on this way,i just make code that use five semaphores because of four semaphore cannot form a stable circular.

```
package exercise.concurrency;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class SemaphoreTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FizzBuzz().start();
    }

}




class FizzBuzz {
    protected AtomicLong num = new AtomicLong(1);
    protected AtomicLong n = new AtomicLong(100);
    protected Semaphore sem1 = new Semaphore(1);
    protected Semaphore sem2 = new Semaphore(1);
    protected Semaphore sem3 = new Semaphore(1);
    protected Semaphore sem4 = new Semaphore(1);
    protected Semaphore sem5 = new Semaphore(1);

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Started");
        try {
            sem1.acquire();
            sem2.acquire();
            sem3.acquire();
            sem4.acquire();
            sem5.acquire();
            this.fizz();
            this.buzz();
            this.fizzBuzz();
            this.printNumber();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void fizz() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 sem1.release();
                 sem5.release();
                while (num.get() <= n.get()) {
                    try {
                        sem1.acquire();
                        sem5.acquire();
                        if (num.get() > n.get()) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (num.get() % 3 == 0 && num.get() % 5 != 0) {
                            num.getAndIncrement();
                            System.out.println("Fizz");
                        }
                        System.out.println("1.fizz one loop");
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                        sem2.release();
                        sem5.release();
                        Thread.yield();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("fizz has finshed");
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void buzz() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (num.get() <= n.get()) {
                    try {
                        sem2.acquire();
                        sem5.acquire();
                        if (num.get() > n.get()) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (num.get() % 5 == 0 && num.get() % 3 != 0) {
                            num.getAndIncrement();
                            System.out.println("Buzz");
                        }
                       System.out.println("2.buzz one loop");
                       TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                       sem3.release();
                       sem5.release();
                       Thread.yield();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void fizzBuzz() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (num.get() <= n.get()) {
                    try {
                        sem3.acquire();
                        sem5.acquire();
                        if (num.get() > n.get()) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (num.get() % 3 == 0 && num.get() % 5 == 0) {
                            num.getAndIncrement();
                            System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
                        }
                        System.out.println("3.fizzBuzz one loop");
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                        sem4.release();
                        sem5.release();
                        Thread.yield();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void printNumber() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (num.get() <= n.get()) {
                    try {
                        sem4.acquire();
                        sem5.acquire();
                        if (num.get() > n.get()) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (num.get() % 3 == 1 && num.get() % 5 == 1) {
                            num.getAndIncrement();
                            System.out.println(num);
                        }
                        System.out.println("4.printNumber one loop\n");
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                        sem1.release();
                        sem5.release();
                        Thread.yield();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

#### It use the `Thread.yield()` to suggest for the thread engine when one thread do once the other one can have chance to do his work.`TimeUnit.Millseconds.sleep()` makes the result looking clearly.

The result looks like this:

```
Started
1.fizz one loop
2.buzz one loop
3.fizzBuzz one loop
2
4.printNumber one loop

1.fizz one loop
2.buzz one loop
3.fizzBuzz one loop
4.printNumber one loop

1.fizz one loop
2.buzz one loop
3.fizzBuzz one loop
4.printNumber one loop

1.fizz one loop
2.buzz one loop
3.fizzBuzz one loop
4.printNumber one loop

1.fizz one loop
2.buzz one loop
3.fizzBuzz one loop
4.printNumber one loop

1.fizz one loop
...
```